# Canvas random images in pattern

Tags: javascript, html, design-patterns, canvas

So far i got the code:

```
var image = new Image();
image.onload = function() {
  // create an off-screen canvas
  var patt = document.createElement('canvas');
  // set the resized width and height
  patt.width = sirinaopto;
  patt.height = sirinaopto;
  patt.getContext('2d').drawImage(this, 0,0, patt.width, patt.height);
  // pass the resized canvas to your createPattern
      drawBG(patt);
image.src = 'img/e.svg'

//repeat background
function drawBG(patternCanvas) {
      var space = ctx.createPattern(patternCanvas, 'repeat');
      ctx.fillStyle = space;
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(zacetek, 0);
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width,  visina2);
    ctx.restore();
    }
```

What this does is create pattern with one image "img/e.svg". Lets say I have 4-5 images (e.svg, e1.svg, e2.svg..... ) How could I create the same pattern but use all of the pictures and use them randomly in the pattern? The patern would look simmilar to: e.svg, e3.svg, e.svg, e2.svg.... instead of e.svg, e.svg, e.svg.....

Comment: Can you share the fiddle of the same ?

Comment: sure https://jsfiddle.net/zcb8Ltpv/

Comment: I'm not sure I clearly got what you want, but it sounds like you just want to draw the whole images onto a bigger buffer canvas randomly, before using it as a pattern, isn't it? But, if you draw like 4 images onto the buffer, then your pattern will just make those 4 images always in the same order, no way to randomize it. If this is what you want, then just don't use pattern ; draw your images at random position

Comment: That would give you something like that : https://jsfiddle.net/2zcfmugp/1/ or that : https://jsfiddle.net/2zcfmugp/2/

Comment: The second one is exactly what I wanted. Thx.

Comment: @markE, that wasn't exactly a good snippet, it didn't created a pattern and I was hoping the question to self-destruct... But I fixed it a little bit, and I hope it will help others too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Randomness is clearly not part of patterns.

Here is a function that will draw a set of images, randomly displayed, over a buffered canvas, then it will return a pattern from this buffered canvas.

You can call like `var pattern = randomPattern();` without any arguments, it will use the first image's width and height in the images array, and the global `canvas` as the area to draw he randomness.
Or, `var pattern = randomPattern(imgWidth, imgHeight, areaWidth, areaHeight);`
where you define a fixed value for your images width, and a strict value for the randomness area
*(this means that if you call it like `randomPattern(20,20,20,20)`, you will actually got only one 20x20 image repeating into the pattern)*.

Note : this function will draw each image with the same width/height.

```js
canvas.width = window.innerWidth>500? window.innerWidth: 500;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight>300? window.innerHeight: 300;
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');


var imagesLoaded = [];

var randomPattern = function(imgWidth, imgHeight, areaWidth, areaHeight) {
  // either set a defined width/height for our images, or use the first one's
  imgWidth = imgWidth || imagesLoaded[0].width;
  imgHeight = imgHeight || imagesLoaded[0].height;
  // restrict the randmoness size by using an areaWidth/Height
  areaWidth = areaWidth || canvas.width;
  areaHeight = areaHeight || canvas.height;

  // create a buffer canvas
  var patternCanvas = canvas.cloneNode(true);
  var patternCtx = patternCanvas.getContext('2d');

  patternCanvas.width = areaWidth;
  patternCanvas.height = areaHeight;

  var xloops = Math.ceil(areaWidth / imgWidth);
  var yloops = Math.ceil(areaHeight / imgHeight);

  for (var xpos = 0; xpos < xloops; xpos++) {
    for (var ypos = 0; ypos < yloops; ypos++) {
      var img = imagesLoaded[Math.floor(Math.random() * imagesLoaded.length)];
      patternCtx.drawImage(img, (xpos * imgWidth), (ypos * imgHeight), imgWidth, imgHeight);
    }
  }

  // create a pattern from this randomly created image
  return patternCtx.createPattern(patternCanvas, 'repeat');
}

var loadImages = function() {
  var imagesToLoad = 4;
  for (var i = 0; i < imagesToLoad; i++) {
    var image = new Image();
    image.onload = function() {
      imagesLoaded.push(this);
      if (imagesLoaded.length === imagesToLoad) {
        draw();
      }
    }
    image.src = 'http://lorempixel.com/50/50?' + i;
  }
};

var draw = function() {
  //create the random pattern (should be moved out of the draw)
  var patt = randomPattern(30,30);
  ctx.fillStyle = patt;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(200, 150, 150, Math.PI * 2, 0);
  ctx.fill();
};

loadImages();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: I tried to draw an object instead of loading an image. I could come up with solution to create pattern with only one  repeating image but im struggling to modify your code in order to work the same as above. I created several hidden canvases (canvasPattern0, canvasPattern1.....) with different object witch should be now randomly loaded.  The jjsfidle with what i came up so far https://jsfiddle.net/zcb8Ltpv/22/

Comment: Append your canvases into the `imagesLoaded` array. : https://jsfiddle.net/zcb8Ltpv/22/

Comment: I tried that but there is still something missing https://jsfiddle.net/zcb8Ltpv/50/

Comment: No, here you are pushing the dataURL (a string version of your canvas) into the array. `drawImage`which is used into the `randomPattern` function, does accept `canvas` elements, so you can directly push your canvas elements into the array.

Comment: Please use the code I provided in the answer, the one you are using was just to be sure what you were asking for. Here you've got an update, with your canvases as the images to be loaded into the pattern https://jsfiddle.net/zcb8Ltpv/55/

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are awesome!

Comment: @Kaiido can you refer to this question [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43324689/how-to-fill-cannvas-circle-arc-with-different-image) i am facing the issue into this. If possible can you help me out